# Need to insert the value of process ID dynamically into a command

Tags: linux, process, centos, file-descriptor

I want to monitor the number of file descriptors opened by a process running on my centos box. the below command works for me

```
watch -n 1 "ls /proc/pid/fd | wc -l"
```

The problem comes when I need to monitor the same when the above process is restarted. The pid changes and I cant get the stats.

The good thing is that the pname is constant. So I can extract the pid using pgrep pname.

So how can I use the command in the below way:

```
watch -n 1 "ls /proc/"pgrep <pname>"/fd | wc -l"
```

I want the `pgrep pname` value to be dynamically picked up.

Is there any way I can define a variable which continuously gets the latest value of `pgrep pname` and I can insert the variable here.

Comment: You want this to update while `watch` is running?

Comment: Not necessarily while watch is running, I basically wanted to capture the value continuously, so thought using watch would be a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch` evaluates its command as shell command each time, so we first have to find a shell command that produces the output. Since there may be multiple matching processes, we can use a loop:

```
for pid in $(pgrep myprocess); do ls "/proc/$pid/fd"; done | wc -l
```

Now we can quote that to pass it literally to watch:

```
watch -n 1 'for pid in $(pgrep myprocess); do ls "/proc/$pid/fd"; done | wc -l'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
watch -n 1 "pgrep memcached | xargs -I{} ls /proc/{}/fd | wc -l"
```

Another one way.